# Pausing react query and re-fetching new data

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a useQuery which is disabled in a react function component. I have another useQuery that uses mutate and on the success it calls refetchMovies(). This all seems to work well but I'm seeing old data in the refetchMovies. Is there a way for to get the refetchMovies to always call fresh data from the server when its called ?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const {data, refetch: refetchMovies} = useQuery('movies', fetchMovies, {
      query: {
        enabled: false
      }
    })

   const {mutate} = useQuery('list', fetchList)
    

    const addList = useCallback(
    (data) => {
      mutate(
        {
          data: {
            collection: data,
          },
        },
        {
          onSuccess: () => refetchMovies(),
          onError: (error) => console.log('error')
        }
      )
    },
    [mutate, refetchMovies]
  )

  return (
    <div onClick={addList}> {data} </div>
  )

   
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is `mutate` returned from `useQuery` - that doesn't exist. Are you talking about a mutation? Anyway, `refetch` just executes the query function unconditionally. if it returns "old data", that seems like a backend issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to invalidate the query in your `onSuccess` callback instead of manually refetching it:
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation

Example:

```js
// Invalidate every query with a key that starts with `todos`
queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['todos'] })
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabio If you invalidate the query onSuccess wouldn’t you still have to refetch it again ? Because enabled:false is set on the query ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to leave the query enabled so it gets automatically refetched as soon as the cache gets invalidated.

Comment: Right but the idea is not to have it making a call to the server when the component mounts hence setting it to enable false. Otherwise it will make an initial call on mount before the onSuccess of the first query happens.